# using a Safe Stored procedure to insert (custom command for any table) a set of values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-injection

this is a stored procedure i have created with help of @Kenneth Fisher,
this works realy good and it is safe (with protection from most sql injection risks)

i would like to make it same way for inserting into database
is it possible with some modification to this code to be able to use this for inserting data ?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SafeSqlSP_SelectGivenTableWithOptionalColFilterVerB] 
    @columnList nvarchar(max) ='*',
    --@tableSchema sysname ='dbo' ,
    @tableName sysname ,
    @ColNameAsFilter1 nvarchar(255) ='',
    @ColNameAsFilter2 nvarchar(255) ='',
    @ColFilter1VAL nvarchar(max)='',
    @ColFilter2VAL nvarchar(max)=''       
    AS

BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    declare @tableSchema sysname ='dbo' ;
    IF ISNULL(@tableSchema,'') = ''
        SET @tableSchema = 'dbo'

    IF ISNULL(@columnList,'') = ''
        SET @columnList = '*'

    SET @tableName = ISNULL(@tableName,'')
    SET @ColNameAsFilter1 = ISNULL(@ColNameAsFilter1,'')
    SET @ColNameAsFilter2 = ISNULL(@ColNameAsFilter2,'')
    SET @ColFilter1VAL = ISNULL(@ColFilter1VAL,'')
    SET @ColFilter2VAL = ISNULL(@ColFilter2VAL,'')

    IF NOT EXISTS (
                    SELECT * 
                    FROM sys.all_objects
                    JOIN sys.schemas
                        ON sys.all_objects.schema_id = sys.schemas.schema_id
                    WHERE sys.all_objects.name = @tableName
                      AND sys.schemas.name = @tableSchema
                      AND [TYPE] IN ('S','U','V')
                    )
        BEGIN
            RAISERROR (N'Table %s.%s does not exist.',
                        16,
                        1,
                        @tableSchema,
                        @tableName)
            RETURN
        END

    IF @columnList LIKE '% FROM %'
        BEGIN
            RAISERROR (N'The column list passed in contains the word "FROM".  This is a SQL Injection risk and not allowed.',
                        16,
                        1)
            RETURN
        END

    IF @columnList LIKE '%;%'
        BEGIN
            RAISERROR (N'The column list passed in contains a semicolon.  This is a SQL Injection risk and not allowed.',
                        16,
                        1)
            RETURN
        END

    IF @ColNameAsFilter1 <> '' AND
        NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                    FROM sys.all_columns
                    WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(@tableSchema+'.'+@tableName)
                      AND name = @ColNameAsFilter1)
        BEGIN
            RAISERROR (N'Table %s.%s does not have a column %s.',
                        16,
                        1,
                        @tableSchema,
                        @tableName,
                        @ColNameAsFilter1)
            RETURN
        END

    IF @ColNameAsFilter2 <> '' AND
        NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                    FROM sys.all_columns
                    WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(@tableSchema+'.'+@tableName)
                      AND name = @ColNameAsFilter2)
        BEGIN
            RAISERROR (N'Table %s.%s does not have a column %s.',
                        16,
                        1,
                        @tableSchema,
                        @tableName,
                        @ColNameAsFilter2)
            RETURN
        END 

    DECLARE @sqlCommand nvarchar(max)

    SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT ' + @columnList + CHAR(13) +
        ' FROM [' + @tableSchema + '].['+ @tableName + ']' + CHAR(13) + 
        ' WHERE 1=1 '

    IF @ColNameAsFilter1 != ''
        SET @sqlCommand = @sqlCommand + CHAR(13) + 
            ' AND ' + QUOTENAME(@ColNameAsFilter1) + ' = @ColFilter1VAL'

    IF @ColNameAsFilter2 != ''
        SET @sqlCommand = @sqlCommand + CHAR(13) + 
            ' AND ' + QUOTENAME(@ColNameAsFilter2) + ' = @ColFilter2VAL'

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlCommand,
            N'@ColFilter1VAL nvarchar(75), @ColFilter2VAL nvarchar(75)', 
            @ColFilter1VAL, @ColFilter2VAL
END
```

Comment: Just curious, but why don't you just write a non-dynamic sproc?  Neither I nor any DBA I know would allow something like this in a production system we work on without a really good reason, but I can't think of any.

Comment: @tommy_o hey tommy , the issue with the stored procedure was to come up with a solution to make CRUD fast easy and also safe against SQL injections while using it as a universal SP (for any given table)

Comment: What middle technology are you using? This type of generic crud operations are usually found in a data access layer or repository layer. Using an ORM like Entity Framework would give you the same reusability without having to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: This is like trying to design a gun that will fire bullets of any size or shape. It's guaranteed to blow up in your face.  After you get out of the hospital, you'll realize that you only ever wanted a handful of variations anyways.

Comment: @Anon thanks forthe illustration i will make it via EF maybe give mvc3 a chance alltogether

Answer (score 1):

Read this first: [Common Cases when to (Not) Use Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#Common_cases)